# laravel - how to display data related to multiple models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have an admin page where I would like to display information about my posts and the campaigns in the system on a single page. There is no relation between campaigns and posts. They are two different aspects of the application .

Right now I have a page where I can display data related to posts and another page where I display data related to campaigns, however this is not what I would like to have.

Any help would be well appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two separate repositories for getting data from these sources - perhaps `GetPostRepository` and `GetCampaignRepository`.

Within these, write separate functions for getting the relevant data you want.  Perhaps `getActiveCampaigns()` in the `GetCampaignRepository` and `getActivePosts` in the `GetPostsRepository`.

Then, in the same controller, inject these new repositories. (Jeffery Way on Dependency Injection: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/dependency-injection-huh/)

You can now run these functions, get your data and send them to your view.  A contrived example below:

```
function showPostsandCampaigns()
{
    $campaign = $this->campaign->getActiveCampaigns();
    $posts = $this->posts->getActivePosts();

    return View::make('view')->with('campaign' , $campaign)->with('posts' , $posts);
}
```

Comment: Hi James .. thank you for your reply.. much appreciated. however i have another doubt please - How do i refer to my Post model within the  GetPostRepository .. sorry for the stupid question - i am still learning laravel .. thanks